# Extract second IP from lines

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Is there a way to extract the second IP address from a command-line output?

Command output

```
Manual NAT Policies (Section 1)
60 (sdf-app-vip) to (outside) source dynamic d-d-servers interface  destination static obj-15.34.4.32 obj-159.13.9.12
    translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 0
61 (ds-app-vip) to (outside) source dynamic d-d-servers interface  destination static obj-15.1.95.176 obj-15.13.5.176
    translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 0
152 (sd-app-vip) to (outside) source dynamic d-d-servers interface  destination static obj-19.36.11.12 obj-19.36.15.12
    translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 0

Auto NAT Policies (Section 2)
115 (nk-app-vip) to (customer-vrf-sd) source static nat-10.19.2.190-customer-vrf-transit 10.223.2.2
    translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 4652
```

My code is able to extract both IP, but am not able to filter the second IP.
Code:

```
import re
#Truncate file
ft=open('puip_only.txt','w')
ft.truncate()
ft.close()
#Filter IP's from object group IP output
cip=open('puip.txt', 'r')
cs=cip.readlines()
for line in cs:
    matches= re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line)
    newlines=( ' '.join(matches))
    outF = open("puip_only.txt", "a")
    outF.write(newlines)
    outF.write("\n")
    outF.close()
```

Expected output is

```
159.13.9.12
15.13.5.176
19.36.15.12
10.223.2.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the second IP, don't join it with the first:

```
if len(matches)>=2:
    outF.write(matches[1])
```

instead of

```
outF.write(newlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the following space, word chars and `-` and then capture the second ip number in group 1.

The group 1 values will be returned by re.findall.

```
\b[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}\s+\w+-([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BpT0Hl/1)